# Optimizing a HashMap with iteration

Tags: java, jdbc, collections, hashmap

I have a `ResultSet` containing 300K records and I am doing the following to iterate it (and other actions once collected). This process takes around 2 minutes to complete. Is there any way to optimize it?

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> internalMap  = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>(); 

while (resultSet.next()) {
    final Integer val1 = resultSet.getInt("val1");
    final String val2 = resultSet.getString("val2");
    final String val3 = resultSet.getString("val3");
    final String val4 = resultSet.getString("val4");
    final String type = resultSet.getString("type");
    final String id = resultSet.getString("id");

    addIntern(internalMap,val2,val1,val3,val4,type,id);
}
```

And the `addIntern` method referenced above

```
private static void addIntern(Map<String,Map<String,String>> internalMap, String val2, Integer val1,
    String val3,String val4,String type,String id) {
    String key = id+"##"+val4;
    if (internalMap.get(key) == null) {
        internalMap.put(key, new HashMap<String,String>());
    }
    internalMap.get(key).put("val3", val3);
    internalMap.get(key).put("val2", val2);


    if("create".equals(type)){
        internalMap.get(key).put("create", val1.toString());
    }
    if("update".equals(type)){
        internalMap.get(key).put("update", val1.toString());
    }
    if("delete".equals(type)){
        internalMap.get(key).put("delete", val1.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need a `Map<String,CustomObject>` instead of a `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`

Comment: @4castle But we are just putting the values. So using it as object or map, both will have the same effect. Right?

Comment: Using a `Map<String, String>` will use more memory and will have less flexibility with the types of values you can store. For example, you're already having to convert `val1` to a `String`.

Comment: Why are you slurping this whole dataset into memory instead of querying it?

Comment: You should analyze your program to see what's taking the most time. Try using a profiler, for example. Various answers here have all focused on using a better data structure, or improving the code of `addIntern`. But really, we have no idea where the time is going. It might not have anything to do with the data structures. I'd guess that the bottleneck is latency in fetching data from the database in `resultSet.next()` but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tune the fetch size from your `resultSet`;

```
resultSet.setFetchSize(100);
```

And you could certainly simplify your add method (each get is an `O(1)` call, but they add up), like

```
private static void addIntern(Map<String, Map<String, String>> internalMap, String val2, Integer val1, String val3,
        String val4, String type, String id) {
    String key = id + "##" + val4;
    Map<String, String> kMap;
    if (internalMap.containsKey(key)) {
        kMap = internalMap.get(key);
    } else {
        kMap = new HashMap<>();
        internalMap.put(key, kMap);
    }
    kMap.put("val3", val3);
    kMap.put("val2", val2);
    if ("create".equals(type) || "update".equals(type) || "delete".equals(type)) {
        kMap.put(type, val1.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to optimize much since you can't reduce number of iterations.

But one change I can see which can be done

```
 if("create".equals(type)){
    internalMap.get(key).put("create", val1.toString());
 }
 if("update".equals(type)){
    internalMap.get(key).put("update", val1.toString());
 }
 if("delete".equals(type)){
    internalMap.get(key).put("delete", val1.toString());
 }
```

Above can be written as below also

```
internalMap.get(key).put(type, val1.toString());
```

This will remove 300k or more if checks.

This will work in a case when your `type` can contain only `create/update/delete` values. If it has more you can put a single `if` to check if it is equal to any one of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. (Java 8)

```
private static void addIntern(Map<String,Map<String,String>> internalMap,
    String val2, Integer val1,
    String val3,String val4,String type,String id) {
    String key = id+"##"+val4;
    Map<String, String> valueMap = internalMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashMap<>());
    valueMap.put("val3", val3);
    valueMap.put("val2", val2);
    if("create".equals(type) || "update".equals(type) || "delete".equals(type))
        valueMap.put(type, val1.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the map initial capacity may help if you have sufficient heap space available:

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> internalMap  = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>(300000*2);
```

By using the default initial capacity, internalMap must be rehashed many times since you are adding 300000 items.